# Coding of categorical random effects in R: int vs factor

Tags: r, categorical-data, mixed-model

I have a problem with coding of a 2-level categorical predictor variable in R, and subsequently using it as a random slope in lmer().

I can keep the factor as numeric, coded using the treatment coding:

```
> unique (b$multi)
[1] 0 1
```

Running lmer() using a dataset coded in this way yields:

```
> l1 = glmer(OK ~ multi + (0 + multi|item) + (1|subject)+ (1|item), family="binomial", data=b)
> summary(l1)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) [glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: OK ~ multi + (0 + multi | item) + (1 | subject) + (1 | item)
   Data: b

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  4806.5   4838.9  -2398.3   4796.5     4792 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-7.8294 -0.5560 -0.1548  0.5623 14.3342 

Random effects:
 Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 subject (Intercept) 1.84379  1.3579  
 item    (Intercept) 2.40306  1.5502  
 item.1  multi       0.04145  0.2036  
Number of obs: 4797, groups:  subject, 123; item, 39
[...]
```

Above there is only one random slope related to `multi`. However, something very different happens when I convert the variable into a factor:

```
> b$multi = as.factor(b$multi)
> levels (b$multi)
[1] "0" "1"
```

When I fit a model using `multi` as a random slope variable:

> l2 = glmer(OK ~ multi + (0+multi|item) + (1|subject)+ (1|item), family="binomial", data=b)
>       Warning message:
>       In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
>         Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues

... the model fails to converge and I get a very different random effects structure:

```
> summary(l2)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) [glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: OK ~ multi + (0 + multi | item) + (1 | subject) + (1 | item)
   Data: b

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  4807.8   4853.1  -2396.9   4793.8     4790 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-8.3636 -0.5608 -0.1540  0.5627 15.2515 

Random effects:
 Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 subject (Intercept) 1.8375   1.3555       
 item    (Intercept) 0.9659   0.9828       
 item.1  multi0      1.5973   1.2638       
         multi1      1.0224   1.0111   1.00
Number of obs: 4797, groups:  subject, 123; item, 39
[...]
```

The number of parameters in the model clearly change (reflected by the change in AIC, etc.), and I get two random slopes.

My question is which way of coding the categorical variable is better? Intuition tells me that it is the first one, but I have seen recommendations for both ways of coding in various tutorials and classes about running GLMMs in R and this is why it baffles me. Both types of the predictor variable work identically in ordinary regression using lm().

Answer (score 4):

The difference is because you're separating the intercept and the slope in the random effect. That's an odd thing to do; the usual way to fit this model would be

```
OK ~ multi + (multi | item) + (1 | subject)
```

with `multi` being a factor.

What happens is that in the first model you get what you expect; the `0+multi|item` term gives one parameter and the `1|item` term gives one parameter, but in the second model the `0 + multi | item` term results in two parameters, which are simply the estimate for each condition. If you take the `1|item` term out of that model you should get a result that is equivalent to both your first model and the one I give above, except for differences in parameterization.

Note also the correlation of exactly one in your second model; this is a clue that you've overparameterized it and that one of those parameters is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, stating the model as `(multi|item)` or `(1+multi|item)` indeed made the two versions of coding the variable work in the same way. 

The reason I specified the model as `(0+multi|item) + (1|item)` is that it removes the correlation term between the random intercept and the random slope - a parameter that increases model complexity but does not help in better controlling type I error rate.

So my take-home message is that if I want to keep the correlation parameter out, I should recode the variable in the first version, i.e. have the contrasts defined as integers, not as factors.

Comment: Well... I'm a little suspect of intentionally not including the correlation term. I think you need it, but I haven't fully thought it through for this model. So don't take it out simply because it makes the model more complex (it's not that complex anyway); take it out instead only if that makes the model match the design of your study better.

Comment: That is at least what these guys found out: [Random effects structure for confirmatory hypothesis testing: Keep it maximal](http://idiom.ucsd.edu/~rlevy/papers/barr-etal-2013-jml.pdf) . Through Monte-Carlo modeling they showed that models with correlation term removed retain high power and near-nominal p-values of the full model. My model BTW is much more complex that that presented above, I just stripped it to demonstrate the problem clearly.

Comment: Looks like an interesting article, thanks. I just read the abstract so far, and will simply note that they emphasize that the model should be "justified by the design," so in that respect, we completely agree.

Comment: hey, just to update this comment thread - Barr et al in "Random effects structure for confirmatory hypothesis testing:
Keep it maximal" state on page 257, item #7: "In terms of power, maximal models perform surprisingly well even in a ‘‘worst case’’ scenario where they assume random slope variation that is actually not present in the population."  In other words, their argument is to ALWAYS include the random slope.  Non-maximal random effects structures can be problematic for hypothesis testing.